# Extending finite rank operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Suppose $Y$ is a closed subspace of Banach space $X$ and $T:Y\to X$ is a bounded finite rank operator. Can we extend $T$ to $\tilde{T}:X\to X$, in the sense that:

- $T=\tilde{T}$ on $Y$
- Range($T$)$=$Range($\tilde{T}$)
- $||T||=||\tilde{T}||$

If $T$ is rank $1$, this follows pretty quickly from Hahn-Banach, but if the rank of $T$ is greater than $1$, I am having trouble with the last bullet, I cannot show the equality of norms.

Comment: Is $T$ continuous?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Yes, bounded finite rank.

Comment: If your space $X$ is a hilbert space I can say yes to this question for any closed subspace $Y$ you can see in H.Breziz Functional analysis exercise 5.15 page 150.

Comment: For general case I don't know if this is true but you can see in :
http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1950-068-01/S0002-9947-1950-0032932-3/S0002-9947-1950-0032932-3.pdf

Comment: Hilbert space is easy, since every subspace is complemented. Just define the extension to be zero on the complement.  I don't think the paper linked helps, it refers to a different, but related problem, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. Kakutani proved that a Banach space $X$ is isometric to a Hilbert space if and only if each two-dimensional subspace $Y$ is complemented by a norm-one projection.

Now suppose that $X$ is not isometric to a Hilbert space and take a two-dimensional subspace $Y\subset X$ such that each projection $P\colon X\to X$ with ${\rm im}\,P = Y$ has norm $>1$. Now take $T$ to be the inclusion map $Tx=x\;(x\in Y)$.

Thus, you can find such extension if and only if $X$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: Nice! I was wondering, for a fixed Banach space $X$, can you find a constant  $C(k)$, such that for any $Y$, any $k$-rank $T$ defined on $Y$ has an extension of norm at most $C||T||$?

Comment: Also no. For instance take $X=c_0$. It contains all finite-dimensional normed spaces isometrically. Take now a sequence of subspaces isometric to Hilbert spaces with increasing dimension. If these space were uniformly complemented, then some ultrapower of $c_0$ would contain a complemented subspace isomorphic to a Hilbert space. This is impossible as ultrapowers of $c_0$ are of the form $C(K)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $K$, so they have the Dunford-Pettis Property. In particular, spaces with DPP cannot have complemented reflexive subspaces.

Comment: Of course, in the above argumentation I still assume that you want to keep the ranges the same. If not, then you can extend compact operators going to $L_1(\mu)$-preduals with $C=(1+\varepsilon)$, where $\varepsilon >0$ is as small as you want. This is Lindenstrauss' theorem.

Comment: Yes, I want ranges the same. This was very helpful, than you.

Comment: @Markus, now I have realised that you want $C$ to depend on $k$. Then the answer is trivially yes as each $n$-dimensional subspace of a normed space is complemented by a projection of norm $n$ (this follows from Auerbach's lemma; actually you can take $\sqrt{n}$--this is the Kadets--Snobar theorem).

Comment: * of norm $\leqslant n$.